# How to keep variables in background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension and came up with a question. That is how can I keep the variables in `background.js`. What "keep" means here is that my variables in `backgrund.js` seems re-initialized and previous data stored in corresponding variables is lost.

I try to use `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage().xxx` to get the variable named `xxx` but the value of `xxx` is lost sometimes.

In `manifest.json` I set the `background.persisitent` to `false`. Is this the root cause ?

Comment: Yes it's the root cause. Either remove it or remove global variables (use chrome.storage and reinitialize the variables).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm! If I use `chrome.storage`, I'm not sure whether the data stores in `Memory` or `DISK`. Thus is there a performance issue ?

Comment: The difference is there certainly, but is it noticeable? You can (and should) measure the real impact by using console.time API or performance.now() or devtools performance profiler for the background page.

Comment: I know what you mean. Thanks, @wOxxOm!