# How to call an async function inside an if statement?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

To [keep variables in background.js in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53983349/3552975) I need to reinitiate some global variables, and I meet some difficulties.

Here is the code([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0ja3m6v/6/)) that I want to use to illustrate the problem:

```
var temp = null; 

function someTimeConsumingThing() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    temp = 10;
  })
}

async function a(){
  if(temp==null){
    await someTimeConsumingThing();
  }
  return temp
}

function b(){
  let localTemp = a();
  console.log(localTemp);
}

b();
```

In the above code snippet, the `temp` variable would sometimes be null and to ensure that temp is not null I should call an async function `someTimeConsumingThing`. As we can see, the console.log outputs a Promise rather than 10; and an error would occur if I add await before a():

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

How can I tackle this problem? I have read many related but unhelpful answers here and I don't know how to optimize my search input to get the most related question. This problem would be very naive for JS experts and there are certainly available answers on this site.

Comment: Why are you (implicitly) opposed to marking `b()` as `async` as well, so that you can successfully `await` your call to `a()`?

Comment: @esqew No, it doesn't work, and I have updated my question by adding some more context.

Comment: "*an error would occur if I add `await` before `a()`*" - uh, not if you also simply add `async`  before `function b() {`?

Comment: I suppose your real `someTimeConsumingThing` is actually asynchronous? Your mock implementation does in fact assign to  `temp` synchronously.

Comment: @Bergi The function b() in my real case is inside `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`, but yes, after a night of sleep I realized that I can add async for the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `await` when calling `a()`, which means you printed the returned promise instead of the async result of `a()`. The containing function therefore also needs to be `async`, since it contains an `await` call.

Note that it's good practice to mark the `someTimeConsumingThing` function as async, because it returns a Promise.

Also note that your `someTimeConsumingThing` function sets temp to 10 immediately, and then delays until returning. I've rewritten it so it only sets temp to 10 after the delay has completed.

```js
let temp = null;

async function someTimeConsumingThing() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      temp = 10;
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })
}

async function a(){
  if(temp==null){
    await someTimeConsumingThing();
  }
  return temp;
}

async function b(){
  let localTemp = await a();
  console.log(localTemp);
}

b();
```

Comment: Thanks. Please check the updates in my question.

Comment: @LernerZhang I don't understand the significance of your question update.  Can you clarify why this answer does not help your specific situation?

Comment: @LernerZhang I'm guessing that your problem is that you're calling async functions from a non-async context, and not understanding that if you call something directly after `b()`, that `b()` will not complete execution before the next statement is executed. You should put all code that calls async functions inside one big async function, and call that async function from the non-async context

Comment: "*Note that it's good practice to mark the `someTimeConsumingThing` function as async*" - no. It's good practice to only mark those functions as `async` that actually use `await`, there's no reason to use `async` for everything that returns a promise.

Comment: @Bergi await is just syntactic sugar. What makes a function async or not is whether it returns a Promise or not, and marking the function explicitly as async when it does return a Promise makes code easier to read

Comment: @AndrewParks It's not just the `await` but also the `async` that is part of the "syntactic sugar", and adding it changes the behaviour of the function. It creates an additional promise which is going to be resolved with the `new Promise`, which is pointless.

Comment: @Bergi you make a good point about doubling up the promises, but it's not clear that this would be a performance hit. I would disagree that it's pointless, since better readability is not pointless. Since non-async functions that return promises create ambiguity over whether they always return a promise, and may throw exceptions outside of the promise mechanism, it's nice for the author to clearly mark a method as reliably returning a promise under all circumstances. There still may be arguments I have not considered that outweigh mine, I'll look out for further arguments in each direction

Answer (score 1):

A function that calls an async function and needs the result of that function, must in itself (by definition) be asynchronous.

Just change `b` so that it is an async function:

```
async function b(){
  let localTemp = await a();
  console.log(localTemp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please check the updates in my question.